# Enrich Mongo documents in Meteor server-side when inserted from client-side?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can't find anything in the docs, but in case I'm missing something, is there any way in Meteor to enrich documents `insert`ed from the client on the server before they're sent to Mongo.

The use-case for this is to handle things like setting up timestamps and other (for server-side use only) fields, without having to set them as part of the document on the client.

The obvious method would be to use `Meteor.call('addMyNewRecord', publicFields)` then `insert` solely from the server-side, but I quite like having the minimongo api on the client-side and I'm hoping to avoid the `call` requirement. I know in CouchDB you can do some basic modifications in their `on-update` handler but can't seem to find anything similar for Meteor/Mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found [a nice approach](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database) to doing this whilst still using the minimongo interface on the client-side.

It seems you can intercept the `insert` and enrich the documents as part of the `Deny` policy, like this:

```
    myCollection.deny({
        insert: function(userId, doc) {
            doc.created = new Date().valueOf();
            doc.creator = userId;
            //other default fields
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've tried to do similar with the `update` Deny policy to add a `modified` field but that doesn't seem to work the same way. As noted in the post linked above, this won't work for the `Allow` policy.

Comment: Nice find.  This is a bit of a hack.  I added a feature request to have something added for this purpose.